# How to filter 3G traffic

Tags: data-monitoring, 3g, filter

Are there a way to block all 3G traffic for specified apps?

Comment: Not without root.  Beyond that I suspect it would have to be a system-level change, not an app.

Comment: What about blocking all internet access for an app?

Answer (score 6):

***If you have a rooted device*** you can filter which specific apps can access the 3G connection with **[DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free)**.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. :) Thank you, Matt

Answer (score 2):

You can block all 3G usage by going to SETTINGS > WIRELESS & NETWORKS > MOBILE NETWORKS and then clciking USE ONLY 2G Networks to disable 3G usage.

There are also lots of widgets available that will allow you toggle between 2G / 3G usage.

Answer (score 1):

[Onavo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid) will let you do this, and it doesn't require your device to be rooted:

"Data hog blocking: Restrict specific apps to Wi-Fi, or block your 3G data altogether once you exceed your data cap to avoid any additional costs"

note that it's only free for a limited time (http://www.onavo.com/help).